# ajax like post or get request from servlet to jsp using java code

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet and a jsp file .

Whenever the servlet is loaded, the servlet needs some instances which can be created only in a JSP(in this case). So, I am thinking of doing some requests to jsp file from servlet as soon as servlet is loaded, so I can get the instances in servlet. How can i do this ?

In python, we can send a get or post request very easily using urllib2 and requests libraries . Is it not possible using java ?

In python, we can do using requests like this :

```
 r = requests.get('url')
```

Thats all , we get the required data from the url into our variable 'r', so we can use that. Is there any similar library in java ?

Comment: That is a very bad approach. Try implementing your problem in a different way. Maybe you can tell us what instances do you need that only a jsp can produce. I am very curious about this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible also this would not be good approach, it will be good do dependency injection to servlet.